# Kill foreground app from service

Tags: android, android-service

I know it is possible to kill background tasks.

Is it possible to kill an app that is currently running in the foreground but a service from another app kill and restart the app?

Comment: You can kill background apps before kitkat version. but you can kill all apps.

Comment: What? Please rephrase your question. It does not parse. Give an example of what you want to do.